# Minimizing simple function of three variables fails

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear, approximation

I need to minimize simple function with all variables are positive integers, but the out is the same as the input. No solution

```
    Clear[α, k, β, g];
g = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
f[α_, k_, β_, g_] := Abs[π - (α/β)*g^k;]
Assuming[α > 0 && k > 0 && β > 0 , 
 Minimize[f[α, k, β, g], {α, k, β}, 
  Integers]]
```

My version is 12.1

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First correct the definition of `f` (semicolon inside argument brackets)

```
g = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
f[\[Alpha]_, k_, \[Beta]_, g_] := Abs[\[Pi] - (\[Alpha]/\[Beta])*g^k]
```

Use `NMinimize` with constraints instead of assumptions:

```
NMinimize[{f[\[Alpha], k, \[Beta], g],Element[{\[Alpha], k, \[Beta]}, PositiveIntegers]}, {\[Alpha],k, \[Beta]} , MaxIterations -> 500]
(*{
```

0.0354583, {[Alpha] -> 3, k -> 3, [Beta] -> 4}}*)

**addendum**

Restricting the parameterrange `{\[Alpha] -<10, k<10, \[Beta] <10}` helps `NMinimize` finding the "right" minimum

```
NMinimize[{f[\[Alpha], k, \[Beta], g], \[Alpha] < 10, k < 10, \[Beta] < 10,Element[{\[Alpha], k, \[Beta]},PositiveIntegers]}, {\[Alpha],k, \[Beta]}  , MaxIterations -> 500]
(*{0.0000481329, {\[Alpha] -> 6, k -> 2, \[Beta] -> 5}}*)
```

Comment: I wonder the upvoters. The answer is wrong.

Comment: Indeed this answer is wrong. If you take the square of f and later the sqrt of the minimum, you can even use Minimize. `f2[\[Alpha]_, k_, \[Beta]_, g] = (\[Pi] - (\[Alpha]/\[Beta])*g^k)^2 //
   ExpandAll; ` `{{min, vars} = 
  Minimize[{f2[\[Alpha], k, \[Beta], g], 0 < \[Alpha] < 300, 
    0 < k < 10, 0 < \[Beta] < 200, 
    Element[{\[Alpha], k, \[Beta]}, Integers]}, {\[Alpha], 
    k, \[Beta]}], Sqrt[min] // N} ` gives `8.4126*10^-6 ` as minimum of f. Minimum shows to be for k == 1 and it tends to zero.  Use `262000 < \[Alpha] < 263000, 134000 < \[Beta] < 136000 ` in above cmd, set k=1.

Comment: @Akku14 Nothing is wrong! If you take the same parameter range `\[Alpha] < 10, k < 10, \[Beta] < 10` as I did , you' ll get the solution given in my answer!

Comment: @user64494 It worked for me

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, the OP is looking for the global minimum for {alpha,beta, k} are PositiveIntegers. This global minimum is not 0.0000481329 as you got with a restricted parameter range. In fact it is as i wrote "Minimum shows to be for k == 1 and it tends to zero" , although it never reaches exact zero. If you take a restricted parameter range, you don't answer the OP and you don't give " the "right" minimum" as you stated.

Comment: @Akku14 Thank you for your answer. I tried to show in my answer, that only for restricted parameter range the problem OP asked for is "numerical" solvable.

Answer (score 4):

The infimum under consideration equals zero. Put `k=1`, then you approximate a number `Pi/g==2*Pi/(1+Sqrt[5])` by a rational number `\[Alpha]/\[Beta]`. This can be done with an arbitrary accuracy, e.g.

```
RealAbs[FromContinuedFraction[ContinuedFraction[(2 \[Pi])/(1 + Sqrt[5]), 
 20]] - (2 \[Pi])/(1 + Sqrt[5])] // N
(*2.22045*10^-16*)
FromContinuedFraction[ContinuedFraction[(2 \[Pi])/(1 + Sqrt[5]),20]]
(*107070177060/55145018711*)
```

Comment: Even simpler: `N[RealAbs[
  Rationalize[(2 Pi)/(1 + Sqrt[5]), 
    10^-30] - (2 Pi)/(1 + Sqrt[5])], 30]` performs `6.33234721355549660014137078117*10^-31`.